# AWS S3 Download: Access Denied, Status Code: 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

So I am utilizing AWS S3 in my Android Application, I have no problem uploading files to S3, but when I try and download them, I am receiving a 403 error, Access Denied.

Here is the Android Code that attempts to download the file:

```
gifFileToShow = new File(gifKey);

TransferObserver s3DownloadObserver = s3TransferUtility.download(
                        keys.getBucket(),
                        fileKey,
                        fileToShow
                );
```

and here is my iAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfiles/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "myfiles/",
                        "myfiles/*",
                        "uploads/",
                        "uploads/*",
                        "public/",
                        "public/*",
                        "protected/",
                        "protected/*",
                        "private/",
                        "private/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "elastictranscoder:Read*",
                "elastictranscoder:List*",
                "elastictranscoder:*Job",
                "elastictranscoder:*Preset"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to add `"Principal": "*"` below `Action": [ "s3:*" ]`, but I receive the error: `This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You must **allow public access** in order to download those files.

Comment: That seems incorrect.  You're suggesting `s3TransferUtility.download()` doesn't use credentials to download?

Comment: It does use credentials in these two lines of code `AmazonS3 awsS3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider, config);`

`s3TransferUtility = new TransferUtility(awsS3, getApplicationContext());`